# Counter based memory array in Verilog

Tags: arrays, counter, verilog

I got a problem. 
I am a Verilog newbie, and I have to write a counter based memory array. Basically, my array is 16 x 8 bits (16 x 1 byte). I have 8 bit data coming into my memory, 16 times. So I made a memory block, and a counter which supplies addresses to this memory block by incrementing with the positive edge of the clock (actually, on each positive edge, 8 bit data is fed into the memory, so I increment my counter). Now I have done this process 16 times, and now 128 bits of data are stored and provided by my memory block. But now I want to reset my counter, and repeat the whole process again after a small delay. I am confused as to how I do this. Please have a look at my code and advise.

Thanking all of you in advance.

```
// creation of counter & a dummy variable
wire cnt;
wire cnt_next;
reg [3:0] counter;
  always @(posedge clock)
    assign cnt_next=cnt+1'b1;   
        counter <= cnt_next
        wire [3:0] write_address  = counter;


//creation of ram function
module single_port_ram
(   
    input [7:0] data,
    input [3:0] addr,
    input wr, clk, rd
    output [127:0] q
);

reg [15:0] ram[0:7];

always @ (posedge clk or posedge reset)
    begin
    // Code for writing the data
        if (wr)
        {
          addr <= write_address 
          case {addr}
                4'b0000: ram[0] <= data
            4'b0001: ram[1] <= data
            4'b0010: ram[2] <= data
            4'b0011: ram[3] <= data
            4'b0100: ram[4] <= data
            4'b0101: ram[5] <= data
            4'b0110: ram[6] <= data
            4'b0111: ram[7] <= data
            4'b1000: ram[8] <= data
            4'b1001: ram[8] <= data
            4'b1010: ram[10] <= data
            4'b1011: ram[11] <= data
            4'b1100: ram[12] <= data
            4'b1101: ram[13] <= data
            4'b1110: ram[14] <= data
            4'b1111: ram[15] <= data
         end

always @ (posedge clk or posedge reset)
    begin
    //Code for reading the data
        if (rd)
        {
        q <= {ram[15],ram[14],ram[13],ram[12],ram[11],ram[10],ram[9],ram[8],ram[7],ram[6],ram[5],ram[4],ram [3],ram[2],ram[1],ram[0]}   
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Make your counter a little bigger, say up to 31 instead of 15. For the first 16 clocks, write the memory address like you are doing, for the next 16 clocks just do nothing but increment (the small delay you wanted), and then when the counter reaches 31 just reset it back to 0. Then the process should restart.

Comment: But how do I 'reset' the counter such that the whole process repeats again? Should I enclose the whole code block in a repeat loop?

Comment: The counter will automatically rollover to 0 once it reaches the maximum value it's field can hold (5'b11111 + 5'b00001 = 5'b00000). Either that or you can choose to set counter back to zero after a certain value (resets back to zero after 25 ticks): `cnt_next = (counter==25) ? 0 : counter + 1`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tim. So all I need to do is increase the counter size, and once it reaches the maximum value, it will reset itself back to 0. That is a great idea. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score -1):

to have 16 x 8 bits (16 x 1 byte)

first you declare the size of your RAM width then you declare the actual depth of your RAM for example if i want an array of 512 reg variables (depth) and each is 8 bits (width) then it will be written like:

```
reg [7:0] ram[511:0];
```

so your code should look like:

```
reg [7:0] ram[15:0];
```